# How can I change the format of a JSON output from iterating through a python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i'm trying to change the format of a json file from:

```
{
    "ordnungsrufe": [
        {
            "date": "1961-04-18",
            "president": "Prof. D. Dr. Eugen Gerstenmaier (CDU/CSU)",
            "wp": "3",
            "protocol": "Protokoll der 154. Sitzung des 3. Deutschen Bundestages",
            "source": "https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/03/03154.pdf",
            "calledOutName": "Adolf Ludwig, MdB",
            "calledOutParty": "SPD"
        }
    ]
}
```

to:

```
[
    {
        "calledOut": {
            "name": "Adolf Ludwig, MdB",
            "party": "SPD"
        },
        "date": "1961-04-18",
        "president": "Prof. D. Dr. Eugen Gerstenmaier (CDU/CSU)",
        "source": {
            "pdf": "https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/03/03154.pdf",
            "sectionFrom": "",
            "sectionTo": "",
            "linkToVideo": ""
        }
    }
]
```

I'have build this python script, but I'm struggling to get the expected format.

```
import json
import codecs

data = json.load(codecs.open('data.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
#print(data)

ordnungsruf = {}

for person in data['ordnungsrufe']:
    ordnungsruf[person['calledOutName']] = {
        "calledOut" : {
            "name": person["calledOutName"],
            "party": person["calledOutParty"]
        },
        "date": person["date"],
        "president" : person["president"],
        "source" : {
          "pdf": person["source"],
          "sectionFrom": "",
          "sectionTo": "",
          "linkToVideo": "",
        }
    }

with open('ordnungsrufe_ordered.json', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(ordnungsruf, json_file, indent=2)
```

my output:

```
{
  "Adolf Ludwig, MdB": {
    "calledOut": {
      "name": "Adolf Ludwig, MdB",
      "party": "SPD"
    },
    "date": "1954-12-08",
    "president": "Prof. D. Dr. Eugen Gerstenmaier (CDU/CSU)",
    "source": {
      "pdf": "https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/02/02059.pdf",
      "sectionFrom": "",
      "sectionTo": "",
      "linkToVideo": ""
    }
  },
}
```

I tried to iterate through the dictionary with several different methods and I'm always failing to get the right JSON. This example seems to be the closest.

Is there a better way to iterate through a dictionary to change the format of a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting results into a list should work:

```
result = []
for item in data['ordnungsrufe']:
    result.append({
        'calledOut': {
            'name': item['calledOutName'],
            'party': item['calledOutParty']
        },
        'date': item['date'],
        'president': item['president'],
        'source': {
            'pdf': item['source'],
            'sectionFrom': '',
            'sectionTo': '',
            'linkToVideo': ''
        }
    })
print(result)
```

N.b. it might be a good idea to save the result as a dictionary:

```
with open('target.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({'items': result}, f)
```

as it will have been a bit more future proof.